# Finding the value of a logarithmic expression involving an infinite GP

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, logarithms

Find the value of $(0.16)^{\displaystyle\log_{2.5}(\frac13+\frac1{3^2}+\frac1{3^3}+\cdots)}$.

I could solve the series. It gave $$(0.16)^{\log_{2.5}0.5}$$

Unable to proceed from here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

HINT:

$$0.16=\frac4{25}=\left(2.5\right)^{-2}$$

$$\text{Now, }\displaystyle a^{\log_am }=m$$

Comment: Formulae of logarithm are available here : http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Logarithm.html, http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Logarithm_Combination_Laws, http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Basic_Properties_of_Natural_Logarithm